# Arraylist cant add new elements

Tags: java, arraylist

so i am trying to add planets to an array that is linked to the solar system. I cant seem to put the name of the planet as a string and radius,distance and mass as doubles

```
public class SolarSystem {

    private String systemName;
    private double luminosity;

    public SolarSystem(String name, double systemLuminosity) {
        systemName = name;
        luminosity = systemLuminosity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return systemName;
    }

    public Double getLuminosity() {
        return luminosity;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (systemName + " has luminosity: " + luminosity);
    }
}

import com.company.SolarSystem;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Planets {

    // Storing planets in an ArrayList
    private ArrayList<SolarSystem> planetList = new ArrayList<>();
    public String name;
    private double mass;
    private double radius;
    private double distance;

    public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double radius, double distance) {
        planetList.add(name, mass, radius, distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You need to use a list of planets, not a list of solar systems. 2. You need to put this list in the `SolarSystem` object.3. you need to pass a new planet to the `add` using a constructor of `Planet` as the other comment states.

Comment: Looking at it in simpler terms, what you have indicates that a planet has Solar Systems (plural), when it should be that a Solar System has planets.

Comment: `You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined that the `planetList` contains `SolarSystem` objects.
Your code does not work because you are adding
`String name, double mass, double radius, double distance`
to the `planetList` when you have defined that the list should contain `SolarSystem` objects.

Answer (score 0):

#### You should consider doing a remodel.

Your direct problem is that you are trying a to pass a `String` as well as `double`s to a list that requires you to pass a `SolarSystem`. So to add such an object to the list you'd have to create it via *e.g.*  `planetList.add( new SolarSystem( systemString, lumVal );`.

However this design is flawed. Your system should hold the list of planets and your `Planets` object representing all planets should be a `Planet` object representing only one planet.

#### Example

In your `SolarSystem`:

```
public SolarSystem(String name, double systemLuminosity) {
    systemName = name;
    luminosity = systemLuminosity;
    List<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double radius, double distance) {
        planetList.add(new Planet(name, mass, radius, distance ));
    }

    // ...rest of the class here

}
```

And your `Planet`:

```
public class Planet {

    public String name;
    private double mass;
    private double radius;
    private double distance;

    public Planet( String name, double mass, double radius, double distance )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

}
```

With this redesign you can create `Planet` objects that hold the properties of a planet. A collection of such objects is then held by your `SolarSystem`.

Note that you could also initialize `Planet` objects elsewhere and let your `addPlanet` function accept `Planet` objects rather than parameters to build a planet, *i.e.:*

```
public void addPlanet(Planet planet){ 
    planetList.add(planet);
}
```

Comment: From the example, you should remove the `planetList` from class `Planet` because it's not used there.

Comment: There is no method `addPlanet` in my demo of `Planet`, that is exactly what I did. What are you talking about?

Comment: Why is there `private ArrayList<SolarSystem> planetList = new ArrayList<>();` in `Planet`?

Comment: This should indeed be removed, as it is copied from the old implementation. However there is no `addPlanet` in `Planet`.

Comment: You are correct. But I have not said anything about `addPlanet`.

Comment: I notice your initial comment is now marked as "edited".